# Schema.org's Microdata date type

Tags: html, date, microdata, schema.org

In what format should I represent the `DATE` type? Schema.org nor Google clarify this.

How does search engines expect it to be? Literal (`April 3rd, 2013`)? `04/03/2013`?

Any information about which (and why) format is preferred will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow microformats.org : 
http://microformats.org/code/hcalendar/creator

Should be :

```
<time datetime="2013-07-08">Example Event</time>
```

Or :

```
<span class="vevent">
 <span class="summary">The microformats.org site was launched</span>
 on <span class="dtstart">2005-06-20</span> 
 at the Supernova Conference 
 in <span class="location">San Francisco, CA, USA</span>.
</span>
```

The microformats.org site was launched on 2005-06-20 at the Supernova Conference in San Francisco, CA, USA.

Read more information about microformats: http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar

Comment: You are talking about [tag:microformats]. jviotti is asking about [tag:microdata]/[tag:schema.org].

Comment: Microformats: the oldest and the simplest of the three. If the existing specs cover your needs (that is, you want to mark up addresses, events, friend links, or another one of the supported data types), then they are a nice and practical choice. The problem is that you cannot make your own microformat if you want to mark up some kind of data that's not supported by the official specs.

I think Microformats is better than microdata, but you can make a new an answer with microdata

Comment: Pieter already [answered the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17531936/1591669).

Answer (score 4):

In ISO 8601 format!

Source: http://schema.org/Date
Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601